# $f(n) \leq \int_{n-1}^{n} f(t) dt$ when $ f \not\in C^1([n-1,n])?$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let f be a decreasing function and
$f:[1,\infty]->[0,\infty]$

is that true that 
$f(n) \leq \int_{n-1}^{n} f(t) dt$ when  $ f \not\in C^1([n-1,n])? $
(Im pretty sure it is the case when $f \in C^1([n-1,n])$).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is a decreasing function then for every $x\in[n-1,n]$ we have $f(x)\geq f(n)$, hence
$$ \int_{n-1}^{n}f(x)\,dx \geq \int_{n-1}^{n}f(n)\,dx = f(n) $$
without further assumptions on the regularity of $f$.